# Going a directory up from main subdomain directory

Tags: jquery, directory, subdomain

I would like to include jQuery into a file that is the main index.php file in subdomain. I've been trying to do it in a standard way:

```
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

However if I open this webpage in let's say test.mywebsite.com (in test subdomain), jQuery doesn't load up, though if I try to do the same from www.mywebsite.com/folder/index.php(which is the folder that "test" subdomain points at) then jQuery loads up. Is there a way to go around this or I'm going to have to duplicate jQuery file and put it into every subdomain that I have in order to use it?

Answer (score 0):

U need to know how directory tree work
src = `../../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`
mean the target is

```
www
    folder
        folder 
             index.php
    js
       jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

are you sure your directory like that?

Comment: 100% sure(it is working on full URL, and not working on subdomain, so that's not the case).

Comment: than U should explain more detail, how is your directory structure. I think it doesn't matter. Or you use .htaccess? I'm not sure if not see detail.
Or U can just move your js at same folder in subdomain. so just link directly. easy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your directory like this

```
 <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

This should work!